# How to get to control userpasswords2 via GUI

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, user-accounts

Is there a way to bring up the User Accounts windows in Windows 7 or 8, which appears when you type "control userpasswords2" via the user interface? I searched for it in every imaginable place and sub-menu, but so far haven't found it. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just found out: the control userpasswords2 practically starts the netplwiz.exe utility. So in order to start it via the GUI, just go to `%windir%/system32` and there double click on netplwiz.exe.

You can also add it as an option to the control panel via this script: [Add User Accounts Utility (Userpasswords2) to Control Panel](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-user-accounts-utility-userpasswords2-to-control-panel/)

Answer (score 6):

2 ways of achieving this:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> | `control userpasswords2` | <kbd>enter</kbd>
2. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> | `netplwiz` | <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: This does not start the tool via the GUI (like from the Control Panel for example), but involves writing commands.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hit the Windows key.
2. Type Users.
3. Click Settings.
4. Click "Change Account Type".

Comment: It's not exactly the same tool as netplwiz.exe. Start both and compare them.

Comment: I'm running Windows 8 Enterprise RTM and it pulls up literally the same UI. As in I ran netplwiz.exe and then followed my instructions and nothing happened, because it was already running. Could be a domain thing maybe.

Comment: When I follow your instructions I get this: 
http://imageshack.us/f/585/31499220.png/

Comment: I see! It must be a Windows 8 SKU difference, it looks like you're running "Windows 8" where I am running "Windows 8 Enterprise". Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I'm also running Enterprise :)

Comment: Ok then it's a group policy setting, because those steps repro 100% for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7,

1) Bring up the Control Panel (e.g., from the Start Menu).

If the Control Panel is in Categories mode (which, I believe, is the default),
2) Click on “User Accounts”, and
3) Click on “Give other users access to this computer”.

If the Control Panel is in Icons mode,
2) Click on “User Accounts”, and
3) Click on “Manage User Accounts”.

Comment: It's not exactly the same tool as netplwiz.exe. Start both and compare them.

Comment: On Windows 7, I don’t see any difference.